# Grails data binding hidden form fields

Tags: forms, grails, data-binding

On my update action i'm submitting a form with hidden fields.
I want to avoid the automatic data binding on the hidden fields (delete the values from the domain object). How can i achieve this in grails?

Thanks

Comment: look at bindData  method http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use exclude as describes in [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/bindData.html). Thanks Aram Arabyan.

```
bindData(target, params, [exclude: ['firstName', 'lastName']], "author")
```